# How to POST array of objects in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a scenario where I fetch products from backend. If no record is found, then I load products.json file which is available locally and add it to database using `http.post` method of Angular.

Here is my code to fetch local data and send it to DB:

```
   ngOnInit() : void {
       //Fetch from DB
       this.productsService.fetchProducts().subscribe(items => {
           if(items.length==0) {
              //Fetch Local 
              const $local =  this.productsService.fetchLocalProducts().pipe(share());

              $local.subscribe((res) => {
    
              res.map(item => {
                  this.productsService.addProducts(item).subscribe(data=> {
                     console.log(data)
                    })
               })
               this.products = res;
           })
        });
     }
   }
```

Here is my service:

```
addProducts(product : Product) : Observable<Product>  {
   const body: Object = { product: product }

   const token: string = localStorage.getItem('token') as string

   const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    })

    return this.http.post<Product>(this.m_baseURL + '/products/', body, { headers: headers})
}
```

Below are the snippets for my Controller and Model Respectively on the server end.

**Controller**

```
export const create = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
   const product : Product = req.body.product
   try {
       const newProduct: DataObject = await model.create(product)
       
       res.status(newProduct.status)
       res.json(newProduct.data)
   } catch (error) {
      res.status(NO_CONTENT)
      res.json(error)
   }
}
```

**Model**

```
async create(prod: Product): Promise<DataObject> {
    try {
      const conn = await Client.connect()
  
      const sql =
    "INSERT INTO products (name, price, quantity, details, avatar) VALUES 
     ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *"
  
      const result = await conn.query(sql, [prod.name, prod.price, prod.quantity, prod.details, prod.avatar])

      conn.release()
  
      const obj: DataObject = {
         status: result.rows.length > 0 ? OK : NOT_FOUND,
         data:
         result.rows.length > 0
         ? result.rows[0]
         : { error: "No Records found" },
     }
     return obj
     } catch (error) {
       throw new Error(`Cannot get product ${error}`)
     }
  }
```

The backend is Okay. But the Angular part is clearly not a good practice. I checked using console.log on my Model method, some of the items don't get saved in DB. Is it due to Observables that so many requests are send and some of them fail for the same reason?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `items.length === 0` instead of `this.products.length == 0`?

Comment: no, it doesn't matter here, but ```(!this.products)``` is better

Comment: @MikeS. yes. It was a silly typo. The main issue, still,  is one with Observables. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: if `items.length` is not `0`, then nothing happens inside of `ngOnInit()`